# WPF: How to Create a Custom View Mode for a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to implement a custom view mode for a `ListView` described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-view-mode-for-a-listview?view=netframework-4.7.2) without success: the view's `WrapPanel` and `ItemTemplate` are not applied. And there is no complete code available, so I do not know how to create a listview object. Here is the complete code from the example above:

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey 
  TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:PlainView},
  ResourceId=myPlainViewDSK}" 
   TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}"
   >
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
      Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" 
      Value="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemContainerStyle,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" 
      Value="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemTemplate,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                               AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
               ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
               MinWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
               ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="centralTile">
        <StackPanel Height="100" Width="90">                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="13" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="9" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:PlainView x:Key="tileView" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource centralTile}" 
         ItemWidth="100"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" />
</Grid>
```

**.cs**

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Entries { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Entries = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Entries.Add("one");
        Entries.Add("two");
        Entries.Add("three");
        Entries.Add("four");
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
        lv.View = lv.FindResource("tileView") as ViewBase;
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: You use local:PlainView what is this?

Comment: `PlainView` is a `ViewBase` class implementation given in the example (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-view-mode-for-a-listview?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the Style to your ListView. I had also some trouble to figgure out how this works with ComponentResourceKey as Key of the style. But finally I got it, see below for your ListView.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"  Style="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:PlainView},ResourceId=myPlainViewDSK}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: And I was thinking that just setting `tileView` resource is enough. Thank you!